# Allure In C# to report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, nunit, allure

i'm doing something new for me which is reporting **Nunit** test cases. After some searching i found out that most of the good reporting tools need an XML file in order to generate the report. I managed to do that. But i want to ask a certain question, is there a way to use a framework named Allure in C# like writing a code that:

> 1)reads the XML file from a certain directory.
>
> 2)generate the report
>
> 3)Finally, save it in a certain path using code in C# in a visual studio project.

Is that possible with **Allure** if not, is there any reporting tool that may do this, i'm not obliged to use Allure, i just need a good reporting tool.

Comment: See about command line http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Commandline

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate Allure results first using [adaptor](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-nunit2). You can try [ExtentReports](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/net/) for .NET. It provides quite the same reporting options. If you have some resource I recommend to try [Report Portal](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal), it also have .NET client.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the Allure.Commons source code you could

1. Read the XML.
2. Process it via Allure.Commons => allure-results generated
3. Call allure serve allure-results

This would provide a super professional result.